# Using SQL "WITH" Clause in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Ok so my environment is XAMPP 7.3.8 and im using PHP with a MSSQL Database. Ive written some code to query the database and the works perfectly fine this issue i'm having is that when I want to wrap the query in a "WITH" clause it stops working. I cannot understand why!

I've tried all types of backticks, single quotes and double quotes. I just dont know where im messing up at!

Working Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',\"Name\")>0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\",1,CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")-1) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Full Package Name\",
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN (select left(\"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\" )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Package Name\",
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\", CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\", (CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")+1))+1))+1))+1)+1,20) ELSE \"Name\" END as 'Version'
    FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'XPF %'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'pkgc%'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'PKG_ADD_%'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_SWV%'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% - %'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_BETA'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%SV1'
    AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% Detection%'
    AND CreatedDate > '2016-1-01 01:50:58.120'";
```

Not Working Code:

```
$sql = "WITH DATASET AS";
$sql .= "(";
$sql .= "SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',\"Name\")>0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\",1,CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")-1) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Full Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN (select left(\"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\" )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\", CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\", (CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")+1))+1))+1))+1)+1,20) ELSE \"Name\" END as 'Version'
        FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'XPF %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'pkgc%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'PKG_ADD_%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_SWV%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% - %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_BETA'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%SV1'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% Detection%'
        AND CreatedDate > '2016-1-01 01:50:58.120'";
$sql .= ")";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM Dataset WHERE RowNum <= 3";
```

**This is the SQL Query Im trying to run in PHP which works perfectly well in SQL SMS:**

```
WITH Dataset AS (
select
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',Name)>0
         THEN SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX('_',Name)-1) 
         ELSE Name END as 'Full Package Name',
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',Name)> 0
         THEN (select left(Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1))
         ELSE Name END as 'Package Name',
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',Name)> 0
         THEN SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_',Name,CHARINDEX('_',name, (CHARINDEX('_',name,(CHARINDEX('_',name,(CHARINDEX('_',name)+1))+1))+1))+1)+1,20)
         ELSE Name END as 'Version',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (select left(Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ORDER BY name DESC) AS RowNum         

from vItem WHERE Name LIKE 'pkg%'
and Name not like 'XPF %'
and Name not like '%.%'
and Name not like '%_SWV%'
and Name not like '% - %'
and Name not like '%_BETA'
and Name not like '%SV1'
and Name not like '% Detection%'
and Name not like 'PKG_ADD_%'
--and CreatedDate >'2016-1-01 01:50:58.120'
)

SELECT * FROM Dataset WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

**This is the full PHP CODE:**

```
elseif(isset($_POST['PKGList'])) {
        $sql = "WITH \"Dataset\" as";
        $sql .= "(";
        $sql .= "SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',\"Name\")>0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\",1,CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")-1) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Full Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN (select left(\"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\" )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\", CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\", (CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")+1))+1))+1))+1)+1,20) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Version\",
        FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'XPF %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'pkgc%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'PKG_ADD_%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_SWV%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% - %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_BETA'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%SV1'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% Detection%'
        AND CreatedDate > '2016-1-01 01:50:58.120'";
        $sql .= ")";
        $sql .= "SELECT * FROM Dataset WHERE RowNum <= 3";

        $params = array();
        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
        $results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $results );
        print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        if ($row_count === false)
            echo "Error accessing package data.";
        else
            echo "";
            //echo $row_count;
            echo "<table class=\"darkTable\">";
            echo "<tr>
            <th>Full Package Name | $row_count Packages</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>Verison</th>
            <th>Build</th>
            </tr>";
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Full Package Name'] . "</td><td>" .  $row['Package Name'] . "</td><td>" .  $row['Version'] . "</td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"PKGList\" value=\"BUILD\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"></td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
            }
            echo "</table>";

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Query successfully sent: ".$sql;
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given

Comment: Please, execute `print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);` after `sqlsrv_query()` call and post the error message. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov it doesnt return anything

Comment: @demo7up It's difficult without full PHP code, but I guess you have errors in your code (`$sql = 'WITH DATASET AS";` should be `$sql = "WITH DATASET AS";` for example).

Comment: @Zhorov i did notice that but it still doesnt work! as of right now I have it as ```$sql = "WITH \"Dataset\" as";```

Comment: I have included the full php statement

Comment: Add a semicolon just before `WITH`

Comment: @demo7up Please, check the result from `sqlsrv_query` and post the result (`$results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options ); if ($results === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;}`). You have an error in your T-SQL statement. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zhorov ```Error (sqlsrv_query): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_num_rows. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_num_rows. ) )```

Comment: @DenisRubashkin like this ```$sql = ";WITH \"Dataset\" as";``` ???

Comment: @demo7up You don't have a `RowNum` column in `Dataset` so `WHERE RowNum <= 3` is probaby the reason for your error.

Comment: @demo7up, yes, if PHP adds statements before the command it could be a problem

Comment: @Zhorov please comment answer so i can accept your answer! Thanks so much I was missing ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (select left(Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ORDER BY name DESC) AS RowNum``` in my php statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation is that there is no column `RowNum` in your `DataSet` CTE. Just correct your T-SQL statement and include `RowNum` column.

```
<?php

$sql = "WITH DATASET AS";
$sql .= "(";
$sql .= "SELECT 
        -- Include RowNum column here ...
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) As RowNum,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',\"Name\")>0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\",1,CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")-1) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Full Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN (select left(\"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\", charindex('_', \"Name\" )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ELSE \"Name\" END as \"Package Name\",
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")> 0 THEN SUBSTRING(\"Name\", CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\", (CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\",(CHARINDEX('_',\"Name\")+1))+1))+1))+1)+1,20) ELSE \"Name\" END as 'Version'
        FROM vItem WHERE \"Name\" LIKE 'pkg%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'XPF %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'pkgc%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE 'PKG_ADD_%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_SWV%'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% - %'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%_BETA'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '%SV1'
        AND \"Name\" NOT LIKE '% Detection%'
        AND CreatedDate > '2016-1-01 01:50:58.120'";
$sql .= ")";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM Dataset WHERE RowNum <= 3";

...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer, but one workaround here would be to just inline the CTE:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%', Name) > 0
                THEN SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', Name) - 1)
                ELSE Name END AS [Full Package Name],
    ...,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (select left(Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name, charindex('_', Name )+1)+1)+1)+1)-1)) ORDER BY name DESC) AS RowNum         
    FROM vItem
    ...
) Dataset
WHERE RowNum <= 3;
```

This should work, assuming that the only problem you had involved using CTEs.