# Get the latest records from database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a sample data

```
id    name      city       status      timestamp
1     John      NYC        active      2022-05-17 12:28:00
2     Kevin     W.DC       active      2022-05-17 12:29:00
3     Ross      NYC       in_active    2022-05-17 12:28:00
4     John      NYC       in_active    2022-05-17 12:29:00
5     Kevin     W.DC      in_active    2022-05-17 12:29:53
```

I'm trying to get the latest records of users in that cities

```
name      city       status      timestamp
John      NYC       in_active    2022-05-17 12:29:00
Kevin     W.DC      in_active    2022-05-17 12:29:53
Ross      NYC       in_active    2022-05-17 12:28:00
```

I'm trying to build this logic in repository function:

```
$model = TableName::with([])
          ->select(['name', 'city', 'status', 'timestamp'])
          ->get();
```

Now my model contains all the records, how can I obtain the required records?

Comment: You can start with `groupBy()`

Comment: If there's 15 attributes, then we have to groupBy them with 15?

Comment: By attributes, you mean city names?

Comment: I mean name, city, country, gender. How does `groupBy()` helps me here?

Comment: Do you wish to get the result city wise or user wise?

Comment: What I mean to say is I want user wise as well as city wise. Let's take there are two users with name `John` but of different cities. In this case, user+city wise would be identifier I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244792/discussion-between-aristotle29-and-nice-dev).

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL 8+` you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte as 
(  select *,row_number() over(partition by name order by `timestamp` desc) as row_num
   from test
 ) select name,city,status,timestamp
   from cte
   where row_num=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=923ecbbbe50bdf31b42525a709270dfa

Comment: I'm looking for the solution in PHP.

Comment: @aristotle29 you can use as a normal query on php. Here you have an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694179/using-sql-with-clause-in-php

Comment: Yeah, but I'd prefer eloquent way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `unique()` like this:

```php
User::latest()->get()->unique('city')
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: okey i'll update my answer

Answer (score -2):

if you want "an eloquent way" check [One Of Many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

```php
//User model
public function latestTableName(){
  return $this->hasOne(TableName::class)->latestOfMany('timestamp');
}

//controller
$model = User::with(['latestTableName'])->get()->pluck('latestTableName');
```

and then return resource with desired fields